# trying to aggregate mapped values

Tags: react-native

I have a react render that maps multiple sites and each site will run a useEffect to pull their current power, I would like to aggregate the current power from each listed site onto the main dashboard.

here is the main dashboard with the useState i want to update

```
const [totalCurrentPower, setTotalCurrentPower] = useState(null)


return (
<div className=' w-[500px] h-[69%]  bg-gray-200 flex flex-col overflow-y-auto space-y-2 py-2'>

                        {site.monitoringSites.map((isite, index) => {
                            console.log(index)
                            return (
                                <div>
                                    <Listedsite  mSite={isite} site={site} total={total} messages={messages === null ? []: messages[index].messages} />
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
                    </div>
)
```

and here is the listed site component

```
const [currentPower , setCurrentPower] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {

        setDevicesOffline(props.mSite.devices.filter((d)=> d.isOnline === false && devicesOffline.isActive).length)

        const asyncfunc = async () => {
            const cp = await solarRequest('GetCurrentpower', {apikey: props.mSite.apikey})
            setCurrentPower(cp)
        }
        asyncfunc()
    }, [])
return ( div class='flex flex-row space-x-4 w-full h-full px-2'>
            <Statistic
            title="Power"
            value={currentPower != null ? currentPower.currentPower.value / 1000 : ''}
            precision={1}
            valueStyle={{
                color: '',
            }}
            prefix={''}
            suffix={currentPower != null ? "kW" : <Spin/>}
            />
</div>
)
```

whenever i try to add each currentpower.value to a state in the main dashboard it overwrites it and gives a wrong number so any help on this would be great.

Comment: The issue should lie in your app architecture which is hard to mitigate with provided information in your question. Can you give more details of your architecture or how the main dashboard and components are related?

Comment: I have a free time now. We should do 1-to-1 meeting if that should help